# python-gnupg vs forked python-gnupg

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, python-3.7, gnupg

I am trying to use the forked version of python-gnupg: https://pypi.org/project/gnupg/
rather than the original: https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/

When I install "gnupg" to my conda environment I see this:

```
$conda list | grep gnupg
gnupg                     2.2.17               he1f381d_0
```

but when I try to import that module, I get this not found error:

```
(my_env) $python
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gnupg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnupg'
>>> import pretty_bad_protocol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pretty_bad_protocol'
>>> from pretty_bad_protocol import gnupg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pretty_bad_protocol'
```

The docs for the forked version say to import gnupg and pretty-bad-protocol, but neither work for me. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Has anyone else had success with this module? Thanks!

Comment: Forked version seems to be for Python 3, 3.3, 3.4. So you cannot use with 3.7.

Comment: Not 100% sure myself, but I think you should use [`python-gnupg`](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/). Even though the version number of [`gnupg`](https://pypi.org/project/gnupg/) is much higher, its latest release is from 2017.